# event handler is not in the namespace

Tags: java, netbeans

If I try to load a screen with a button called "vorige" it go's in an error.
This is the error I got :

[image]

I find it strange because the logout button works in exactly the same way and there is no error there. If I remove the onAction method in the FXML file the exception is gone.

Kind regards

Fietsschermcontroller

```
@FXML
private Button buVorige;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */   
    public void setMain(Vivesbike main) {
     this.main = main;
}

/**
 *
 * @param vorigeEvent
 */
public void Vorige(ActionEvent vorigeEvent){
    main.loadBeginscherm();
  }
```

Fietsscherm FXML

```
<Button fx:id="buVorige" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Vorige"    prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Vorige" />
```

This function is in the main

```
    public void loadBeginscherm(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("view/Beginscherm.fxml"));
        BeginschermController controller = new BeginschermController();
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        controller.setMain(this);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setTitle("Keuzescherm");
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Fout tijdens het laden van het beginscherm: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

        public void loadFietsscherm(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("view/Fietsscherm.fxml"));
        BeginschermController controller = new BeginschermController();
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        controller.setMain(this);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setTitle("Fietsscherm");
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Fout tijdens het laden van het fietsscherm: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post full xml and controller code? Looks like you only show it for logout button.

Comment: I thought that was the important code. I will edit this in a minute with full code

Comment: You load view/Beginscherm.fxml or Fietsscherm Fxml? Please provide both. And both places how you're loading them.

Comment: Its a button in english called "back" to go back to the previous screen. I load beginscherm if I press that button.

Comment: Is the entire code necessary? because the rest of the code has nothing to do with the button. greetings

Comment: I can't see in the code where you load Fietsscherm Fxml. I can only see Beginscherm.fxml. Is there a typo somewhere or you've not posted the full code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121864/discussion-between-dylanbeginner21-and-artem-novikov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loadFietsscherm method you connect BeginschermController to Fietsscherm.fxml, but I'm sure FietsschermController is implied to be there.

Comment: Hi, I made a misstake in my question. The code is updated now